# how do i embed my bots reply with say command discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

on my say command it's not embedded so it lets members @everyone I want to embed the bot's reply to prevent that.

i tried other embeds but they did not work out due to them being
outdated i tried my own but it did not work
command I use:

```
client.on('message',
function(msg){
    if(msg.content === "v!say"){
```

I don't lnow what to put after

Answer (score 3):

There are several things you could do on this

FYI `message` is deprecrated and you should use the event listener below:

```js
client.on(`messageCreate`, async (msg) => {
    // code here
};
```

Prevent @everyone and @here

```js
if(msg.content === `v!say` && !msg.content.includes(`@everyone`) && !msg.content.includes(`@here`){
    let message2send = //however you already do this

    await msg.channel.send({
        content: message2send,
    });
}
```

Embed Message

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require(`discord.js`);
//put at top of file

if(msg.content === `v!say`){
    let message2send = //however you already do this

    let embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setDescription(message2send)

    await msg.channel.send({
        embeds: [embed],
    });
}
```

Do Both

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require(`discord.js`);
//put at top of file

if(msg.content === `v!say` && !msg.content.includes(`@everyone`) && !msg.content.includes(`@here`){
    let message2send = //however you already do this

    let embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setDescription(message2send)

    await msg.channel.send({
        embeds: [embed],
    });
}
```

UPDATE: this answer is not for Discord.js v14+ as MessageEmbed is now EmbedBuilder

Comment: did embed but it errored

Comment: What error @Lightindahouse